# Работа с Google maps в Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, google-maps, windows-phone-7, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Начал работать с Windows Phone 7, пишу тестовое приложение с использованием 
Google Maps. Не могу решить, казалось бы, тривиальную задачу: при клике на карту
получить координаты этого места. Задача вроде бы простейшая, но что-то меня заклинило.

Кто знает, объясните.

P.S. В качестве основы брал вот эту статью: [Simple GPS Locator for Windows Phone 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225318/Simple-GPS-Locator-for-Windows-Phone-7)

Comment: Без кода и описания того, как вы это делаете, боюсь, что вряд ли вам кто-нибудь сможет помочь. Вариантов интеграции `Google Maps` и `WP7` - несколько, и в каждом случае ответ на ваш вопрос будет разным.

Comment: А не поделитесь ссылкой, как вообще заюзать GMaps на WP7, я думал там пока есть только Bing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это?

```
<my:Map  x:Name="MapControl" Grid.Row="1"
        LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Visible"
        CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</my:Map>

private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var point = new Point(e.GetPosition(MapControl).X, e.GetPosition(MapControl).Y);
    var location = MapControl.ViewportPointToLocation(point);
}
```

Comment: @alvin, нет, проблема как раз такая же, как и у меня(правда я делал немного по другому, но суть та же). Этот метод возвращает координаты точки на элементе(относительно его высоты/ширины), а надо вернуть координаты точки на карте(то есть ее широту/latitude и долготу/longitude). Проверить крайне легко, надо щелкнуть в правый нижний угол экрана, координаты будут около {450,450}. Такой широты и долготы быть не может.

Comment: @Olter согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.viewportpointtolocation.aspx) метод должен возвращать `Location` (ширину, долготу, etc).

Comment: @AlexeyM, это вы говорите про метод ViewportPointToLocation, он действительно конвертирует точку(point) в тип location. Проблема в том, что у точки будут неверные координаты.

Comment: правильные там координаты, что вы выдумываете только что проверил и всё работает. Приведите свой код и я скажу где ошибка

Comment: Тьфу ты, выводил на экран point.X/Y вместо location.Latitude/longitude. Принимаю ответ.